# $2016$ is unique number because of its consecutive divisors from $1-9$. Find the next whole number with the same property

Tags: factoring, gcd-and-lcm

> > $2016$ is unique number because of its divisors (1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9). Find the next whole number with the same property!

First, I know that $2016$ have $36$ divisors: $$1, 2, 3, 4,6,7,8,9,12,14,16,18,21,24,28,32,42,48,56,63,72,84,96,112,126,144,168,224,252,288,336,504,672,1008,2016$$
With a prime factorization of:
$$2^5 \times 3^2 \times 7$$

---

How do I continue? Hints Only.

Comment: Which *consecutive divisors* are you referring to? $5\in[1,9]$ is not a divisor of $2016$.

Comment: See also [What is the secret of number 2520](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177630/what-is-the-secret-of-number-2520).

Comment: If there is another number with the same property, then 2016 wouldn't be unique, would it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number is divisible by $2,3,4,6,7,8,9$ if and only if it is a multiple of $$lcm(2,3,4,6,7,8,9)=504$$ After $2016$, the next number is $2520$

Comment: Although, the OP did say hints only..

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that only hints are wanted.